# How to disable the shortcut for New Profile in command line (Terminal)

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, shortcuts

I was playing around terminal and I came across Terminal Preference. Under that there is a tab called Shortcut where I accidentally enabled shortcut for New Profile as Q. Now whenever I press Q on terminal a new profile is created. I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

How do I disable that? Here is the snapshot of what happened:

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Double click on that `Q` and then press `Backspace`.